# Issue while Running transactions through Node Explorer via cordapp-example flows :ExampleFlow$Initiator

Tags: blockchain, corda

[link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fAotG.png)I tried with the Beta version of Corda Node explorer for a visual UI of the operating nodes,peers,notary and the vaults.

It is working fine.

When I am performing the transactions over CLI, It is getting reflected on the Node Explorer,but facing issue while trying to transact over UI.

I am trying to do a transaction with ExampleFlow$Iniator flow, but I am not getting the option to create a transaction over UI.

Will it not work with the cordapps of samples/cordapp-example?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it should work with the cordapp-example. To be able to run flows you need to provide the path of the folder containing the cordapp in the Settings tab.

Have a look at the demo here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cn2lhS8pjRs

Comment: Yeah,I went through this video and did exactly for cordapp_example ,also tried with obligation_cordapp, for cordapp_example, only 1 flow is getting loaded on UI, ExampleFlow$Initiator and the other tabs are not getting populated on UI. I am trying on Linux Ubuntu.

Comment: I dont really understand your problem, the cordapp_example just has one flow. Which other tabs are not populated ?

Comment: Other tabs like when you are clicking on the selected flow, a constructor type, lender,amount and anonymous fields are not loading.

Comment: That's weird, is that the case for some other cordapp as well. Have you checked of the flow has a constructor

Comment: Yes,The flow has the constructor. I checked for obligation-cordapp and cordapp-exampe. Is there any other initial steps for node explorer ? I just downloaded the node-explorer linux downloadable file in the link and deployed cordapp nodes  and set the path in settings.

Comment: I will ask someone to take a look over the Linux installer.

Comment: I think it is the problem with the Linux one, I am successfully running all the cordapps in Windows now. Thanks!

Comment: Yah, I guess so, we have raised a bug to investigate. Thanks.